# how to use fmt:message tag inside <![CDATA[?

Tags: jsp, localization, jstl, cdata

I have following properties in file messages.properties:

```
   more=more
details.more=more
details.More=More
```

Following lines in my jspx page:

```
<![CDATA[
<a omniture-tracking class="ABC" href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="$('#def').css('display', 'none');$('#ghi').css('display', 'block')">
            <fmt:message key="details.more"/>
</a>
]]>
```

Expected:
I want "more" should come with hyperlink with the condition mentioned in tag.

Actual:
Nothing is appeared.

Experimentation:
I tried the following:

```
<![CDATA[
<a omniture-tracking class="ABC" href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="$('#def').css('display', 'none');$('#ghi').css('display', 'block')">
            more
</a>
]]>
```

And it worked fine with hyperlink.`enter code here`

Comment: Answer depends on why exactly you need that CDATA block. As this is really a strange construct, this in turn suggests that you incorrectly thought that using a CDATA block would be the right solution to a certain problem which you tried to solve beforehand. The answer would then be to just replace that wrong solution (the CDATA block) by the right solution, so that your current problem with `<fmt:message>` is instantly also solved. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your recommendation. Please look at the answer posted by me which solves it.

Comment: You only "solved" (workarounded) Y not X. You will run into more Y-problems in the future as long as you don't solve X-problem. Keep in mind to blame yourself instead when you're almost about to blame JSP/JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below, my issue is resolved:

```
<![CDATA[
<a omniture-tracking class="ABC" href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="$('#def').css('display', 'none');$('#ghi').css('display', 'block')">
]]>
<fmt:message key="details.more"/>
<![CDATA[
</a>
]]>
```